# Overview of 3rd party platform sdks or libraries for Android

Tags: android, sdk, amazon-web-services, libraries, facebook-android-sdk

I'm still somehow new to android and I've struggled a bit to find a place where I can have an overview of available 3rd party platform sdks for android, such as: facebook SDK, onecloud sdk (for using box.com), AWS Sdk (for using Amazon Web Services) and so on.

I was looking for some resource equivalent to the API listing you can retrieve from [Programmable Web API directory](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory) but for available SDKs for Android. I understand that actually most of the APIs listed on the API directory above can be accessed by android using XMPP, REST, etc. But I am looking specifically on what is already packaged through a SDK which does not only hides the networking part, but may implement caching or other convenient features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, I just found a very good overview of available sdks and libraries for Android in the [AppBrain website](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/dev). If someone knows a better resource, please share

Answer (score 3):

Check [here](http://edgar.tumblr.com/post/2060687444/a-list-of-3rd-party-libraries-for-android) , There is a list but you can find new libraries every day. Always search for them and have a look at programming forums.